# Visual Studio Data Load from flat file to Postgres Database

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio, ssis

I am using Visual Studio to transfer data from a CSV file to the Postgres database. My database is installed on windows server 2012 and I'm using my local machine to transfer data. My process runs successfully without throwing any errors but somehow it's not loading all the rows of my CSV file. The file contains 382,363 rows but after I check my database only 26000 rows have been loaded.

I directly loaded the CSV from the import wizard of Postgres and it successfully loaded all the 382,363 rows but when I'm loading data through visual studio it just loads 26000 rows without throwing any error. I just get two warning msgs. Has anyone faced any issue if so how do I solve it?

Pasting below the entire output of my process

```
SSIS package "C:\Users\Shivam SARIN\source\repos\Integration Services Project3\Integration Services Project3\Package.dtsx" starting.

Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.

Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.

Warning: 0x80049304 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Warning: Could not open global shared memory to communicate with performance DLL; data flow performance counters are not available.  To resolve, run this package as an administrator, or on the system's console.

Warning: 0x80047076 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: The output column "T_CTRY_DESTINATION" (115) on output "Flat File Source Output" (6) and component "Flat File Source" (2) is not subsequently used in the Data Flow task. Removing this unused output column can increase Data Flow task performance.

Information: 0x40043006 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Prepare for Execute phase is beginning.

Information: 0x40043007 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Pre-Execute phase is beginning.

Information: 0x402090DC at Data Flow Task, Flat File Source [2]: The processing of file "C:\Users\Shivam SARIN\Documents\Excel-csv\MS 2018 Q3.csv" has started.

Information: 0x4004300C at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Execute phase is beginning.

Information: 0x402090DE at Data Flow Task, Flat File Source [2]: The total number of data rows processed for file "C:\Users\Shivam SARIN\Documents\Excel-csv\MS 2018 Q3.csv" is 382364.

Information: 0x402090DF at Data Flow Task, OLE DB Destination [275]: The final commit for the data insertion in "OLE DB Destination" has started.

Information: 0x402090E0 at Data Flow Task, OLE DB Destination [275]: The final commit for the data insertion in "OLE DB Destination" has ended.

Information: 0x40043008 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Post Execute phase is beginning.

Information: 0x402090DD at Data Flow Task, Flat File Source [2]: The processing of file "C:\Users\Shivam SARIN\Documents\Excel-csv\MS 2018 Q3.csv" has ended.

Information: 0x4004300B at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: "OLE DB Destination" wrote 382363 rows.

Information: 0x40043009 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Cleanup phase is beginning.

SSIS package "C:\Users\Shivam SARIN\source\repos\Integration Services Project3\Integration Services Project3\Package.dtsx" finished: Success.

The program '[21956] DtsDebugHost.exe: DTS' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with postgres, I found that using the oledb destination to insert rows was incredibly slow and weird things as you noted above seemed to happen.  It's slow because the provider does not support bulk insert operations.

My suggestion is to call psql with an `Execute Process Task`.  This will be much faster and you will be using tooling that is native to postgres.

More on that here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/app-psql.html

Comment: Hi Mark, I'm a little newbie in Postgres, can you please elaborate your comment on how to do with psql.